# Limiting remainder in php

Tags: php

I have a code in which calculates the Effective interest rate.
when I echo it I get 5.1161897881733 which I want to limit the remainder and output it like 5.11, is there any functions use to limit the remainder in php?

Comment: round() floor() ceil() .... more infos on www.php.net

Comment: php doesn't provider "remainders". you want to limit decimal places.

Comment: yes I want to limit decimal places how can I do it?

Comment: Hi Danilo, take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php , the second argument is the precision (number of decimal places), you should set it to 2 to get the output you want.

Comment: To `round()` it all up from the `floor()` to the `ceil()` you can `substr()` or `number_format()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A billion ways to do this. The task for you here is to pick one.

### Method 1 - round()

This will just round your number. The exact rules can be found in the PHP.net documentation.

```
round($someNumber, 2);
```

### Method 2 - floor()

Floor will round the number down

```
floor($someNumber, 2);
```

### Method 3 - ceil()

Opposite to floor() this will round your number upwards.

```
ceil($someNumber, 2);
```

### Method 4 - number_format()

This will format any number. `number_format()` has a gazillion possible inputs in which you can choose decimal characters etc.

```
// Will round your number to 2 decimals with a . as decimal character
number_format($someNumber, 2, ",", ".");
```

Feel free to edit and add more options :)

Answer (score 0):

```
round($result, 0)
```

The 0 represents the decimal places.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php